# 'Unbusy' terminals which will be logged out when TMOUT is reached

Tags: ssh, terminal, tty, telnet, timeout

I would like auto-logout some terminal sessions with a TMOUT (timeout) configuration, but in that case the users leave a program opened for which the 'unbusy' sign is the ZERO I/O between server and terminal.

I would like to query the 'unbusy' terminals, to apply some logic of exceptions, such as which kind of program is running, how long it has been running, and the source IP (telnet/ssh).

Is that possible? How?

Comment: What do you mean by “I/O between server and terminal”? Is this only about users connected over SSH, and I/O on the SSH connection?

Comment: No. Some pts can be connected from telnet, also. And others can be real tty (physical ports RS232).